# can you tell me the solution please

Tags: npm

```
C:\Users\PC>npm run
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\PC/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\PC\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-13T12_49_39_466Z-debug-0.log
```

i try to run the expo

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure that inside the directory you are at "at your terminal" there is a package.json file to run npm i

and you may need to install all packages before you run any npm scripts run :

```
npm i
```